# Why Path.Combine() disrespects ".." (up one folder level)?

Tags: .net, directory, path

Using ".." to jump up one level is the oldest feature of file system navigation - EVERY command line utility support it! (yes, thanks to OS shell)
But when you use Path.Combine(), it works as a stupid string concatenator! Sample:

```
Path.Combine(@"c:\abc\def", @"..\XYZ")
```

Obviously we expect `c:\abc\XYZ`, while real result is `c:\abc\def\..\XYZ`. What a reason to embed `Combine()` into Path class if it knows nothing about elementary folder syntax? Same way it could be coded as String.Combine().

Is there any .NET solution, which can handle path concatenation properly?

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately there is simple solution - use standard function:

```
Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(@"C:\dir1\dir2", "..\dir3\file.txt")) => C:\dir1\dir3\file.txt
```